# undefined method `current_page' for #<Array:0x2461e18> using kaminari gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my controller

```
 @calsp = 'CALL explode_table('+@clientcodestr+','+@clientnamestr+')' # it excute the procedurr format
 @clientoutput = UserRegister.fetch_db_records(@calsp)
 Kaminari.paginate_array(@clientoutput).page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

in my views

```
<%= paginate @clientoutput %>
```

Comment: Note that unless you already have explicitly escaped `@clientcodestr` and `@clientnamestr` before building your `@calsp` variable, you have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Comment: Now Delete this question with a low score of 2. @raghava goud

Answer (score 1):

Change following in to controller

```
 @calsp = 'CALL explode_table('+@clientcodestr+','+@clientnamestr+')' # it excute the procedurr format
 @clientoutput = UserRegister.fetch_db_records(@calsp)
 @clientoutput = Kaminari.paginate_array(@clientoutput).page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

Method `Kaminari.paginate_array` returns modified array which can be passed in to paginate method. so you need to use this return value in view. And for that I have saved the same value in variable `@clientoutput`.